# How to integrate MLpack C++ based Machine learning model with seldon core

Tags: seldon

Integrate MLpack C++ based Machine learning model with seldon core

Tried to  integrate MLpack C++ based Machine learning model with seldon core

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to wrap your model in the Seldon Core C++ wrapper before deploying it. Instructions can be found here:
https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/cpp/README.html